# Spacy lemmatizer issue/consistency

Tags: python, spacy, lemmatization

I'm currently using spaCy for NLP purpose (mainly lemmatization and tokenization). The model used is en-core-web-sm (2.1.0).

The following code is run to retrieve a list of words "cleansed" from a query

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(query)
list_words = []
for token in doc:
    if token.text != ' ':
        list_words.append(token.lemma_)
```

However I face a major issue, when running this code.
For example, when the query is "processing of tea leaves".
The result stored in list_words can be either ['processing', 'tea', 'leaf'] or ['processing', 'tea', 'leave'].

It seems that the result is not consistent. I cannot change my input/query (adding another word for context is not possible) and I really need to find the same result every time. I think the loading of the model may be the issue.

Why the result differ ? Can I load the model the "same" way everytime ? Did I miss a parameter to obtain the same result for ambiguous query ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried to run your example and results I am receiving are consistent --> ['processing', 'of', 'tea', 'leaf']. Could you share more details?

Comment: I've found the issue, to reproduce this you have to reload a python session (meaning that for the same interpreter instance, it'll produce the same result).
The fix is explained here : https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/3646

Hope it'll help other people

Comment: It is very interesting and understandable - thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was analysed by the spaCy team and they've come up with a solution.
Here's the fix : https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/3646

Basically, when the lemmatization rules were applied, a set was used to return a lemma. Since a set has no ordering, the returned lemma could change in between python session.

---

For example in my case, for the noun "leaves", the potential lemmas were "leave" and "leaf". Without ordering, the result was random - it could be "leave" or "leaf".