# SpaCy use Lemmatizer as stand-alone component

Tags: spacy, lemmatization

I want to use SpaCy's lemmatizer as a standalone component (because I have pre-tokenized text, and I don't want to re-concatenate it and run the full pipeline because SpaCy will most likely tokenize differently in some cases).

I found the lemmatizer in the package but I somehow needs to load the dictionaries with the rules to initialize this Lemmatizer.
These files must be somewhere in the model of the English or German model, right? I couldn't find them there.

```
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
where do the LEMMA_INDEX, etc. files are comming from?
lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES)
```

I found a similar question here: [Spacy lemmatizer issue/consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55864933/spacy-lemmatizer-issue-consistency)
but this one did not entirely answer how to get these dictionary files from the model. The spacy.lang.* parameter seems to no longer exist in newer versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an extracted bit of code I had, that used the SpaCy lemmatizer by itself.  I'm not somewhere I can run it so it might have a small bug or two if I made an editing mistake.

Note that in general, you need to know the `upos` for the word in order to lemmatize correctly.  This code will return all the possible lemmas but I would advise modifying it to pass in the correct `upos` for your word.

```
class SpacyLemmatizer(object):
    def __init__(self, smodel):
        import spacy
        self.lemmatizer = spacy.load(smodel).vocab.morphology.lemmatizer

    # get the lemmas for every upos
    def getLemmas(self, entry):
        possible_lemmas = set()
        for upos in ('NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADJ', 'ADV'):
            lemmas = self.lemmatizer(entry, upos, morphology=None)
            lemma = lemmas[0]    # See morphology.pyx::lemmatize
            possible_lemmas.add( lemma )
        return possible_lemmas
```